# Advantage of using JsonSerializer kafka over manually parsing String

Tags: java, jackson, spring-kafka

Are there any advantages or disadvantages for using JsonDeserializer in kafka consumer over manually parsing received JSON String using Jackson inside the application?

Will be there any kind of impacts in performance etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> advantages

Less code for you to write.

There should be no performance impacts since the deserializer is doing exactly the same thing that your code would be.

It will be decoded directly from the `byte[]`. If you use a `StringDeserializer` and decode it yourself, there would be an unnecessary `byte[]->String` conversion.

If you want to do it yourself for some reason, better to use a `ByteArrayDeserializer` and consume it as a `byte[]`.